# Open <li> tag of footer upward on toggle during mobile view (no added css framework)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made my own responsive footer without any css framework but on mobile view it becomes toggle.
The problem is when i toggle the button it toggles downward, not upward. Thank you.

Please check the code snippet if how do I deal on toggling upward.

If you guys think there is more appropriate and good approach to make good responsive footer, it would gladly be much appreciated.

But in this case, I am just missing something. Thank you

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".footer-toggle-btn").click(function() {

    if ($(this).text() == "☰") {
      $(this).text("✖");
      $('.footer-container').css('display', 'block');

    } else {
      $(this).text("☰");
      $('.footer-container').css('display', 'block');

    }
    $("#footer li").toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.footer-container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0px 5%;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
}

.footer-container li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.footer-container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.footer-container ul {
  width: 65%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

nav {
  width: 100vw;
}

.footer-toggle-btn {
  display: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 50px;
  font-size: 23px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.footer-toggle-btn:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: #f39700;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #footer {
    height: auto !important;
  }
  .footer-container {
    display: block;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .footer-container ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .footer-container a {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .footer-container li {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
  }
  .footer-container li:hover {
    background-color: #f39700;
  }
  .footer-container li:hover a {
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .footer-toggle-btn {
    display: block;
  }
}

#footer {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="footer">
  <footer class="footer-container">
    <ul class="feed-list">
      <li><a href="#">TEST 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">TEST 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">TEST 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">TEST 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">TEST 5</a></li>
      <button class="footer-toggle-btn">✖</button>
    </ul>
  </footer>
</section>
```

Comment: It's a footer and If you move the footer to bottom, obviously the toggling will be upward what is the problem in that? am I missing something here?

Comment: Oh M G! how did i miss that. Thank you. Basically I never put my body content first that's why my footer was still on top

Comment: just adding content may not solve the problem, you need to position it to bottom `#footer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}`